# Get value from long string

Tags: php

I have a HTML String below .

```
<?php $str="<td class="team_info" align="center" height="26"><strong>Match Time：<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">formatDate('2017,6,11,23,30,00',1)</script>7/12/2017&nbsp;06:30&nbsp;Wednesday &nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></td>"
?>
```

I want to get string '2017,6,11,23,30,00' and put each numbers into array. Please help . Thank friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code:

```
$str="<td class=\"team_info\" align=\"center\" height=\"26\"><strong>Match Time：<script language=\"Javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">formatDate('2017,6,11,23,30,00',1)</script>7/12/2017&nbsp;06:30&nbsp;Wednesday &nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></td>";

preg_match("/'([0-9,\s]+)'/", $str, $matches);
if(count($matches) > 1) {
    print_r(explode(',', $matches[1]));
}
```